# How can update my scraped data without updating all the values but only the values that were updated (i.e crypto currency)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have been building a Rails App to scrape and show the last Foreign Exchange Reference Rates.

I have two views:

- index.html.erb : Shows with a "collection_select" all the countries scraped and a button to search the rate's country.
- show.html.erb : Shows the rate of the selected country.

My table has 3 columns :

1. Short (i.e USD)
2. Country (i.e United States)
3. Rate (i.e 1.234)

On the show view there is a button to go back to the index for a new research (with refreshed rates --> with the same scraping)

I would like to update only the scraped updated values, (NOT if there are not updated)

This is my first post, I hope this is clear enough .. ! Thanks in advance

> My controller:

```
class CurrenciesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    Scraper.new.save
    @currency = Currency.new
  end

  def show
    @currency = Currency.find(params[:currency][:id])
    Currency.destroy_all
  end

  def update
  end

end
```

> My scraper:

```
class Scraper

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

  def initialize
    @array = []
    url = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html"))
      url.css('tbody>tr').each do |row|
        hash = {}
        hash['Short'] = row.css('.currency').text
        hash['Country'] = row.css('.alignLeft').text.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
        hash['Rate'] = row.css('.rate').text
        @array << hash
      end
    @array
  end


  def save
    @array.each do |currency|
      Currency.create(short: currency["Short"], country: currency["Country"], rate: currency["Rate"])
    end
  end

end
```

> My schema :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_01_29_113433) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "currencies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "short"
    t.string "country"
    t.float "rate"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

> My index:

```
<h1>Euro Foreign Exchange Reference Rates</h1>
<br>
<div class="text-center">
  <%= form_for @currency, url: show_path do |c| %>
  <p>Choose your Foreign Exchange Reference</p><br>
  <%= c.collection_select :id, Currency.order(:country),:id,:country, {include_blank: false} %>
  <br><br><br>
  <%= c.submit "Search", ({:class => 'btn btn-light btn-sm'}) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

> My show

```
<div class="text-center">

  <h2>
    <%= @currency.country %>
  </h2>
  <br>
  <p>1€ =
    <%= @currency.rate %>
    <%= @currency.short %>
  </p>
  <p class="time"> <%= @currency.created_at.strftime("Updated on %d/%m/%Y at %k:%M UTC")%></p>

  <h3>
    <a href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/eurofxref-graph-<%= @currency.short.downcase %>.en.html" target="_blank">-->
      <%= @currency.country %>
      Exchange Reference Rate
      <-- <b </a> </h3> <br>
        <p><%= link_to "New Research with updated rates", root_path, :class => 'btn btn-light' %></p>

</div>
```

Comment: How do you know whether value was updated or not?

Comment: When you scrap a second time, the scraper gets all the same values and compares, if it has changed then i want to keep the more recent one

Comment: So, it's a simple `if` then? If you detect change, then save it, else continue to the next record.

Comment: Hey Sergio, I am actually struggling, can you give a hint (don't give me the answer plz haha). There are shitloads of if you reload the index page... Feel free to check it out https://euro-foreign-exchange-rates.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Why is every currency repeated 3 times? :)

Comment: Because everytime I do another research it scraps again ....

Comment: If a currency exists, don't create a new one, update the one that exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question entirely but isn't this a simple case of checking if what you have recently scraped is not equal to what you have on the database; then you update with the new values.

```
currency = Currency.where(country: hash['Country'])

if currency.rate != hash['Rate']
  currency.rate = hash['Rate']
  currency.save
end
```